# Custom filter not working in objects

Tags: json, data-binding, polymer

How to make my custom filter work using bind?

**Not Working Example:**

JSON:

```
{ "name": "Adrian" }
```

HTML:

```
<template bind="{{user}}">
  <p>{{name | filterName}}</p>
</template>
```

But it works normally when i use repeat.

**Working Example:**

JSON:

```
[
  { "name": "Adrian 1" },
  { "name": "Adrian 2" }
]
```

HTML:

```
<template repeat="{{user in users}}">
  <p>{{user.name | filterName}}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had defined filterName as a function under the elements's prototype...

```
Polymer('my-element', {
  filterName: function(value){
    return value.toUpperCase()
  }       
});
```

When we do

```
<template>
   {{ user.name | filterName }}
<template>
```

you have access to your element and its properties 'user', 'users' and the filterName callback.

When you do

```
<template>
  <template bind="{{user}}">
     {{name | filterName}}
  </template>
</template>
```

Your outer template has access to user and filterName.

But your inner template is now bound to see only the user object. Your scope is limited to user now. This is a special case when you use bind.

More info here... https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-patterns/blob/master/snippets/basics/using-bind-to-create-a-single-template-instance.html

Nevertheless, there are options for you:

1- Less than ideal -> add the callback as a property in your object. Your model now is responsible for dom transformations. Sucks!

2- If you were to reuse the filter you can turn it into a global expression

```
PolymerExpressions.prototype.filterName = function (value) {
  return value.toUpperCase();
};
```

And now you can use anywhere.